# Which one is correct and why?( "a' before name)

Tags: grammar

Should I use "a" before a name when referring to a part of someone like "fan"?

1) I'm a Ronaldo fan.

2) I'm a Ronaldo's fan.

3) I'm Ronaldo's fan.

Comment: (1) is the usual way to say it. (3) is possible, (2) is wrong.

Comment: Could you explain why (2) is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Number 1 is correct, and would be widely understood in the way intended. Number 2 is wrong in all circumstances. Number 3 is grammatically correct but it implies that Ronaldo has just one fan, and that you're owning up to it.

I can see why a non-native speaker might want to give Ronaldo a possessive apostrophe here, after all, we're talking about a fan OF Ronaldo. But in fact, we think of 'Ronaldo fan' as a composite entity rather than two distinct words with distinct grammatical roles to play.